# Python - convert string to array

Tags: python, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a string that I want to convert to an array in python. The string has a few possible formats:

1. `Xstart(xstep)Xend,X2`.
2. `Xstart(xstep)Xend`
3. `X1,X2,X3`
4. `X1`

For example:

1. `6(6)24` should give me [6,12,18,24].
2. `6(6)24,48` should give me [6,12,18,24,48]
3. `6,24,42,50` should give me [6,24,42,50]
4. `6` should give me [6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive solution without using a regex could be to just split on `','` and then look for the presence of an opening parenthesis indicating the presence of a `step`:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from typing import NamedTuple

def str_to_extracted_list(s: str) -> list[int]:
    extracted_list = []
    s_parts = s.split(',')
    for part in s_parts:
        if '(' in part:
            opening_pos = part.find('(')
            ending_pos = part.find(')')
            start = int(part[:opening_pos])
            step = int(part[part.find('(') + 1:part.find(')')])
            end = int(part[ending_pos + 1:])
            x = start
            while x <= end:
                extracted_list.append(int(x))
                x += step
        else:
            extracted_list.append(int(part))
    return extracted_list

class TestCase(NamedTuple):
    s: str
    expected: list[int]

def main() -> None:
    t = PrettyTable(['s', 'expected', 'actual'])
    t.align = 'l'
    for s, expected in [TestCase(s='6(6)24', expected=[6, 12, 18, 24]),
                        TestCase(s='6(6)24,48', expected=[6, 12, 18, 24, 48]),
                        TestCase(s='6,24,42,50', expected=[6, 24, 42, 50]),
                        TestCase(s='6', expected=[6])]:
        t.add_row([s, expected, str_to_extracted_list(s)])
    print(t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| s          | expected            | actual              |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 6(6)24     | [6, 12, 18, 24]     | [6, 12, 18, 24]     |
| 6(6)24,48  | [6, 12, 18, 24, 48] | [6, 12, 18, 24, 48] |
| 6,24,42,50 | [6, 24, 42, 50]     | [6, 24, 42, 50]     |
| 6          | [6]                 | [6]                 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```